# IOS remote notifications not working in background for IOS 8

Tags: c#, ios, ios8, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have been using Xamarin.IOS, and I recently came across the problem of trying to receive a remote notification payload when the Iphone/Ipad is in background. IOS 7 devices seem to be working when in background or in forground. However, for the IOS 8 devices the DidReceiveRemoteNotification is only called if the alert banner is touched. I need to be able to get the payload when alert banner is not touched and application is in background. Why are remote notifications working in background for IOS 7 but not for IOS 8. What could I be doing wrong?

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion [0] >= '8')
    {
        UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert;
        UIUserNotificationSettings settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes (types, null);
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings (settings);
    }
    else
    {
        UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge |                                                      
        UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes (notificationTypes);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the RegisterForRemoteNotifications method if the version is iOS 8 or greater like so:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion [0] >= '8')
{
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes (types, null);
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings (settings);
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
}
```